# Reading a text file from URL gives wrong string back

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm reading a text file (.txt) from my own server in my app and i put it in a string like this:

```
NSString *vers= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lnk] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

The problem is that even on my server it says the number `1371135679`, in my app it shows me the old number which is `1371133137`. So for some reason it doesn't execute that line or something? Does anybody got any idea how I can fix this, maybe it has something to do with cache I'm just guessing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with HTTP caching: just add `?t=<timestamp>` (or a random value) to the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```